# Find out whether values exists in other table within time range

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to evaluate whether a user's action is performed in relativity to another action. Both actions are marked with a timestamp.

What I want to evaluate is whether a user when she has an entry in one table e.g. `A` (both tables has the same `ID` for an individual user) has an entry in another table, `B`, in between the time of entry in `A` and 5 minutes earlier. I manage to extract time for all values

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(playdatetime - 5/(24*60),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') five_min_future, 
  TO_CHAR(playdatetime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') jetzt, 
  TO_CHAR(SEARCHDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ses_time
```

I tried to make something like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN TO_CHAR(SEARCHDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
          BETWEEN TO_CHAR(playdatetime - 1/(24*60),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
       AND 
       TO_CHAR(playdatetime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END timediff
```

but how could I get this to just check for one user and not just evaluate the row at hand?

Comment: :I am confused sorry ,table with data will be helpful to understand and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query shows records that exist in both `a` and `b`, where the record in `b` occurs up to 5 minutes before that in `a`:

```
select a.user_id,
       a.event_dt,
       b.event_dt
from   a
join   b
on     b.user_id  = a.user_id
and    b.event_dt between (a.event_dt - (5 / (60 * 24))) and a.event_dt;
```